# Modifying the polyData points/vertices in VTK

Tags: c++, 3d, vtk

I'm trying to use VTK to change points, i.e. I am changing coordinates (x,y,z) by a (+1/-1) value. I am reading an .OBJ file and then accessing the points of a model and when I am trying to visualise the changes in the model the RenderWindow doesnt show anything. Below is my code:-

```
vtkSmartPointer<vtkOBJReader> reader = vtkSmartPointer<vtkOBJReader>::New();
reader->SetFileName(filename.c_str());
reader->Update();

vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyData> polyData = reader->GetOutput();
polyData->Update();

Point3d point;
std::vector<Point3d> vertices; 

double p[3];        
vtkPoints* points = vtkPoints::New();       
vtkDoubleArray* pcoord = vtkDoubleArray::New();

pcoord->SetNumberOfComponents(3);       
pcoord->SetNumberOfTuples(polyData->GetNumberOfPoints());

for(vtkIdType i = 0; i < polyData->GetNumberOfPoints(); i++) 
{  
    polyData->GetPoint(i,p);
    p[0] +=1;
    p[1] +=1;
    p[2] +=1;
    pcoord->SetTuple(i, p);       
}

points->SetData(pcoord);
polyData->SetPoints(points);   
polyData->Modified();

//Visualize Code

vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyDataMapper> mapper = vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyDataMapper>::New();
mapper->SetInputConnection(reader->GetOutputPort());

vtkSmartPointer<vtkActor> actor = vtkSmartPointer<vtkActor>::New();
actor->SetMapper(mapper);

vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderer> renderer = vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderer>::New();
renderer->AddActor(actor);

vtkRenderWindow* renderWindow = vtkRenderWindow::New();
renderWindow->AddRenderer(renderer);

vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderWindowInteractor> renderWindowInteractor = vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderWindowInteractor>::New();
renderWindowInteractor->SetRenderWindow(renderWindow);

renderWindowInteractor->Initialize();
renderWindowInteractor->Start();
```

I am new to this 3D and VTK stuff, Please check where I am missing since I want to change the coordinates of each vertex (x,y,z). Do I need to further change something else as well?

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First thing, you have alignment issues in the code that you included in your question. I believe you are missing a for loop too. (where is "i" defined?)

The major issue is that you are not rendering polyData at all. The only thing you are rendering is what is in the .obj file. Evident from this line:

```
mapper->SetInputConnection(reader->GetOutputPort());
```

In order to render polyData replace the above line with:

```
mapper->SetInputData(polyData);
```

This assumes polyData was created correctly. I can't easily tell this from the code you provided.

[Here](http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Cxx/PolyData/Silhouette) is an example that may help.

Comment: I have also tried with that command line earlier but nothing appears on the rendering window :/
for my vtk the command is

 mapper->SetInput(polyData);

Comment: Did it compile like that? It should be "SetInputData" See this [link](http://www.vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkPolyDataMapper.html#acc442e69006a90a371959eec6c1ee74e)

Comment: Yes it did compile using the mapper->setInput(polyData)..

But actually this does not show any changes in the model..!!
What i Did extra is 

reader->Modified();

and then it started showing the model but still.. the changes in the vertices are not being saved in Obj file. I used below code to save the changes :-

vtkOBJExporter* objExporter = vtkOBJExporter::New();
objExporter->SetRenderWindow(renderWindow);
  objExporter->Write();

Comment: Ok. Did using vtkOBJExporter solve the issue? You should edit your original question to have to most up to date version of your code. Try it with "SetInputData." The reason why I say this can be seen in the only link of my first comment from August 5th.    

Also, I am getting confused on the workflow. Are you wanting to open a .obj, modify the data, and then display it. And that is it? Or do you need to save a new .obj file?    

Last, is there a program that you could modify the .obj file in separately that you are more comfortable in? That might be the easiest way.

Comment: Actually I wanted to open .obj file and then do some changes and save as a new .obj file..!!
I would like to do it with same vtk.